# PostgreSQL 9.4.2 installation restricted access to my admin account on OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql, root, postgresql-9.4

I installed PostgreSQL 9.4.2 on Mac 10.10.3 Yosemite, including pgAdmin, phpPgAdmin, pgAgent. After the installation I couldn't open 'system preferences' or any other apps on Mac therefore I restarted the system and logged back in to my account named 'Admin'. After logging in, instead of contents from account 'Admin' I saw account of a new user 'pgAgent' and this appears to have replaced 'Admin' user account name in 'Users & Groups' under 'System preferences'.

When checking via the command line, I can see all my folders in the user root folder, but I can only look inside those folders that I created myself. So all Apple default folders on account 'Admin' are visible but have restricted access and I can't obtain access even after using sudo command and typing admin password.

Can someone help me figure out what is happening and how can I get back my admin account?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?